# Understanding the solution

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Notation : $M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ denotes the set of all modular forms of weight k on $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$

$E_k=1-\frac{2k}{B_k}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_{k-1}(n)q^n$

Now the exercise :

Let f be a modular form of weight k for the full modular group
whose Fourier expansion at $i\infty$ is given by $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{2\pi inz}  \  \ , \  \ a_n \in \mathbb{C}$$ 
There are unique $c_{ab}$'s such that  $$f(z)=\sum_{4a+6b=k} c_{ab}E_4^aE_6^b  \  \ , \  \ c_{ab} \in \mathbb{C}$$ 
Let F be an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ . Suppose that $$ \# \lbrace  n:a_n \in F\rbrace \ge dim M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})).$$
Then , show that $c_{ab}$ belong to F , whence all the Fourier coefficients belong to F.

Solution :

We begin by noting that the Fourier coefficients of $E_4$ and $E_6$ are rational (in fact, integral). Inserting the q-expansions of f and $E_4^aE_6^b$ in our
expression, and comparing the coefficients of $q^n$ on both sides for exactly  $dimM_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$  many values of n  such that $a_n \in F$ , we get a system of
linear equations satisfied by the $c_{ab}$ say , $A(c_{ab})=v$ , for some matrix A with rational entries and vector v with entries from F.

Now the uniqueness (and the existence) of complex numbers $c_{ab}$ imply the
invertibility of A. Since A has rational entries, so does $A^{-1}$ . But  then , the $c_{ab}$'s belong to F
 .

I do not  really understand  how to get the system of linear equations .

Comment: Are you sure it is not asking to pick the $\dim M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ first coefficients ?

Comment: yes , this exercise you also find in the book " Problems in the  Theory of Modular Forms " .

Comment: It is not obvious at all any coefficients work, are you sure, if so then it must have proven some theorems about linear dependence of the coefficients equivalently of Hecke operators

Comment: Hecke operators come in a later chapter .

Comment: If so it is a mistake, $M_k(SL_2(Z)$ is of dimension $N$ it means for some $n_1,\ldots,n_N$, it doesn't mean for any $n_1,\ldots,n_N$, the map $f \mapsto (a_{n_1}(f),\ldots,a_{n_N}(f))$ is injective.